# Not able to access tomcat URL, where as curl of http:hostip:port is resulting in output

Tags: linux, tomcat

I have installed tomcat-8.5.23 in Linux and it is running fine. I have tried running the curl command as below, and it is resulting in the output. Where as i am trying to access the url(http://hostIp:8181/) from internet explorer resulting in timeout error.

```
$curl http://hostIp:8080/
output: 


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <title>Apache Tomcat/8.5.23</title>
        <link href="favicon.ico" rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" />
        <link href="favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
        <link href="tomcat.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="wrapper">
            <div id="navigation" class="curved container">
                <span id="nav-home"><a href="http://tomcat.apache.org/">Home</a></span>
                <span id="nav-hosts"><a href="/docs/">Documentation</a></span>
                <span id="nav-config"><a href="/docs/config/">Configuration</a></span>
                <span id="nav-examples"><a href="/examples/">Examples</a></span>
                <span id="nav-wiki"><a href="http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FrontPage">Wiki</a></span>
                <span id="nav-lists"><a href="http://tomcat.apache.org/lists.html">Mailing Lists</a></span>
                <span id="nav-help"><a href="http://tomcat.apache.org/findhelp.html">Find Help</a></span>
                <br class="separator" />
            </div>
            <div id="asf-box">
                <h1>Apache Tomcat/8.5.23</h1>
            </div>
            <div id="upper" class="curved container">
                <div id="congrats" class="curved container">
                    <h2>If you're seeing this, you've successfully installed Tomcat. Congratulations!</h2>
                </div>
                <div id="notice">
                    <img src="tomcat.png" alt="[tomcat logo]" />
                    <div id="tasks">
                        <h3>Recommended Reading:</h3>
                        <h4><a href="/docs/security-howto.html">Security Considerations HOW-TO</a></h4>
                        <h4><a href="/docs/manager-howto.html">Manager Application HOW-TO</a></h4>
                        <h4><a href="/docs/cluster-howto.html">Clustering/Session Replication HOW-TO</a></h4>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="actions">
                    <div class="button">
                        <a class="container shadow" href="/manager/status"><span>Server Status</span></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="button">
                        <a class="container shadow" href="/manager/html"><span>Manager App</span></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="button">
                        <a class="container shadow" href="/host-manager/html"><span>Host Manager</span></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!--
                <br class="separator" />
                -->
                <br class="separator" />
            </div>
            <div id="middle" class="curved container">
                <h3>Developer Quick Start</h3>
                <div class="col25">
                    <div class="container">
                        <p><a href="/docs/setup.html">Tomcat Setup</a></p>
                        <p><a href="/docs/appdev/">First Web Application</a></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col25">
                    <div class="container">
                        <p><a href="/docs/realm-howto.html">Realms &amp; AAA</a></p>
                        <p><a href="/docs/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html">JDBC DataSources</a></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col25">
                    <div class="container">
                        <p><a href="/examples/">Examples</a></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col25">
                    <div class="container">
                        <p><a href="http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/Specifications">Servlet Specifications</a></p>
                        <p><a href="http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/TomcatVersions">Tomcat Versions</a></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br class="separator" />
            </div>
            <div id="lower">
                <div id="low-manage" class="">
                    <div class="curved container">
                        <h3>Managing Tomcat</h3>
                        <p>For security, access to the <a href="/manager/html">manager webapp</a> is restricted.
                        Users are defined in:</p>
                        <pre>$CATALINA_HOME/conf/tomcat-users.xml</pre>
                        <p>In Tomcat 8.5 access to the manager application is split between
                           different users. &nbsp; <a href="/docs/manager-howto.html">Read more...</a></p>
                        <br />
                        <h4><a href="/docs/RELEASE-NOTES.txt">Release Notes</a></h4>
                        <h4><a href="/docs/changelog.html">Changelog</a></h4>
                        <h4><a href="http://tomcat.apache.org/migration.html">Migration Guide</a></h4>
                        <h4><a href="http://tomcat.apache.org/security.html">Security Notices</a></h4>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="low-docs" class="">
                    <div class="curved container">
                        <h3>Documentation</h3>
                        <h4><a href="/docs/">Tomcat 8.5 Documentation</a></h4>
                        <h4><a href="/docs/config/">Tomcat 8.5 Configuration</a></h4>
                        <h4><a href="http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FrontPage">Tomcat Wiki</a></h4>
                        <p>Find additional important configuration information in:</p>
                        <pre>$CATALINA_HOME/RUNNING.txt</pre>
                        <p>Developers may be interested in:</p>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="http://tomcat.apache.org/bugreport.html">Tomcat 8.5 Bug Database</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/docs/api/index.html">Tomcat 8.5 JavaDocs</a></li>
                            <li><a href="http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/tomcat/tc8.5.x/">Tomcat 8.5 SVN Repository</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="low-help" class="">
                    <div class="curved container">
                        <h3>Getting Help</h3>
                        <h4><a href="http://tomcat.apache.org/faq/">FAQ</a> and <a href="http://tomcat.apache.org/lists.html">Mailing Lists</a></h4>
                        <p>The following mailing lists are available:</p>
                        <ul>
                            <li id="list-announce"><strong><a href="http://tomcat.apache.org/lists.html#tomcat-announce">tomcat-announce</a><br />
                                Important announcements, releases, security vulnerability notifications. (Low volume).</strong>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="http://tomcat.apache.org/lists.html#tomcat-users">tomcat-users</a><br />
                                User support and discussion
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="http://tomcat.apache.org/lists.html#taglibs-user">taglibs-user</a><br />
                                User support and discussion for <a href="http://tomcat.apache.org/taglibs/">Apache Taglibs</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="http://tomcat.apache.org/lists.html#tomcat-dev">tomcat-dev</a><br />
                                Development mailing list, including commit messages
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br class="separator" />
            </div>
            <div id="footer" class="curved container">
                <div class="col20">
                    <div class="container">
                        <h4>Other Downloads</h4>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="http://tomcat.apache.org/download-connectors.cgi">Tomcat Connectors</a></li>
                            <li><a href="http://tomcat.apache.org/download-native.cgi">Tomcat Native</a></li>
                            <li><a href="http://tomcat.apache.org/taglibs/">Taglibs</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/docs/deployer-howto.html">Deployer</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col20">
                    <div class="container">
                        <h4>Other Documentation</h4>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/">Tomcat Connectors</a></li>
                            <li><a href="http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/">mod_jk Documentation</a></li>
                            <li><a href="http://tomcat.apache.org/native-doc/">Tomcat Native</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/docs/deployer-howto.html">Deployer</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col20">
                    <div class="container">
                        <h4>Get Involved</h4>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="http://tomcat.apache.org/getinvolved.html">Overview</a></li>
                            <li><a href="http://tomcat.apache.org/svn.html">SVN Repositories</a></li>
                            <li><a href="http://tomcat.apache.org/lists.html">Mailing Lists</a></li>
                            <li><a href="http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FrontPage">Wiki</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col20">
                    <div class="container">
                        <h4>Miscellaneous</h4>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="http://tomcat.apache.org/contact.html">Contact</a></li>
                            <li><a href="http://tomcat.apache.org/legal.html">Legal</a></li>
                            <li><a href="http://www.apache.org/foundation/sponsorship.html">Sponsorship</a></li>
                            <li><a href="http://www.apache.org/foundation/thanks.html">Thanks</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col20">
                    <div class="container">
                        <h4>Apache Software Foundation</h4>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="http://tomcat.apache.org/whoweare.html">Who We Are</a></li>
                            <li><a href="http://tomcat.apache.org/heritage.html">Heritage</a></li>
                            <li><a href="http://www.apache.org">Apache Home</a></li>
                            <li><a href="http://tomcat.apache.org/resources.html">Resources</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br class="separator" />
            </div>
            <p class="copyright">Copyright &copy;1999-2017 Apache Software Foundation.  All Rights Reserved</p>
        </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

Below is the error message i am getting in accessing the url from the internet explorer.
    This site can’t be reached

```
<hostip> took too long to respond.
Search Google for <hostip> 8181
ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT`enter code here`

Could you please help me what went wrong here? Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Balakrishna K
```

Comment: Um, 8181 isn't the same port as 8080?

Comment: Thank you  Davis, I have tried with ports 8080 and 8181 in server.xml file and in both the cases, i could able to access the url using the curl but not able to access it using the url from internet explorer.

Comment: No: your `curl` command uses port 8080, while your IE error shows port 8081.